# how to import port color from json to graph in joint js inside angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, jointjs

I am trying to add custom ports to a shape model in JointJS within an Angular application. However, when I attempt to import the shape from JSON to the graph, the port colors and styles do not appear to work properly. Here is my code for defining the ports

```js
private ports = {
  groups: {
    in: {
      position: 'top',
      attrs: {
        '.port-body': {
          r: '6',
          fill: '#0000ff',
          magnet: true,
        },
        '.port-label': {
          fill: 'transparent',
        },
      },
    },
    out: {
      position: 'bottom',
      attrs: {
        '.port-body': {
          r: '6',
          fill: '#ff0000',
          magnet: true,
        },
        '.port-label': {
          fill: 'transparent',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And here is the code for the element:

```
if (!this.closeSw) {
  this.closeSw = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
    id: 'closeSw',
    type: 'closeSw',
    size: { width: 50, height: 50 },
    position: {x: 200, y: 200},
    attrs: {
      '.label': { text: 'My Element', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2 },
      rect: {
        width: 100, height: 50,
        rx: 2, ry: 2,
        fill: '#2ECC71'
      }
    },
    ports: this.ports,
    inPorts: ['in'],
    outPorts: ['out'],
  });

  this.canvasGraph.addCell(this.closeSw);
}
```

ports are linking to variable magnet is also working.
When I convert the element to JSON and try to import it, the port colors disappear in the JSON view. Additionally, I attempted to use the markup approach, but it seemed to override the ports' functionality, and I was unable to link the ports. Here is the markup string I used:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1zwM.png) when i convert it to json and try to import from json ports color dissappaer in json view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QulqN.png)

i used ports api but it does not make any changes and i tried to use markup which override the ports functionality and i was unable unable to link ports.
using markup string
markup: '<circle r="6" fill="red" />',

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eph1.png)
I want to achieve custom port colors along with the linking functionality. How can I achieve this?